# How to create , update and delete objects in my API using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

i managed to list all the objects that i created with the admin side in Django . I'm now trying to create , update or delete objects with django rest framework . I already tried some code but it didn't succeed , i got plenty of Assertion errors .

Here is my models.py  :

```
class Etudiant(models.Model):

 id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
 nom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 prenom=models.CharField(max_length=20)

 cne=models.CharField(max_length=10)
 email=models.EmailField()
 tel=models.CharField(max_length=10)

 def __str__(self):
     return 'Nom : {} , Prénom : {}'.format(self.nom,self.prenom)
```

my views.py :

```
class EtudiantList(APIView):

 def get(self,request):
  etudiants=Etudiant.objects.all()
  serializer=EtudiantSerializer(etudiants,many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'^etudiants/',views.EtudiantList.as_view()),
```

]

my serializers.py :

```
class EtudiantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta :
     model=Etudiant
     fields='__all__'
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: If you want to stick to simple APIView, please have a look at this: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/creating-a-django-api-using-django-rest-framework-apiview-b365dca53c1d

I'd suggest you to follow the approach used in the following link:
https://codeburst.io/create-a-django-api-in-under-20-minutes-2a082a60f6f3

Comment: Thank you that helped me understanding a lot of things , I tried all this and it worked , but how can i add , update or delete via the url ?

Comment: What do you mean by the URL?

Comment: for instance , is it possible to send a request like that : 127.0.0.1:8000/etudiants/delete/2 to delete the object with id number 2 ?
Just to make this more clear , I need to use this API for an android App , so as an administrator , i must be able to delete , create or change the users that are stored in my database .

Comment: This is explained in the links that I shared above

Comment: I'm trying the following in Postman : 127.0.0.1:8000/etudiants/10 
But it gives me the following error : TypeError at /etudiants/10
delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' .

Comment: Why though ? i specified the pk .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191474/discussion-between-yassine-el-baaj-and-d3corator).